# Why are my x-axis's dates being displayed as 40 years in the past?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have simple time series data comparing two search terms (`banana bread` and `pumpkin bread`) which I'm getting from the `pytrends` module:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=240)

# requests the data from pytrends, which returns a DataFrame
kw_list = ['banana bread', 'pumpkin bread']
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='US')
df = pytrends.interest_over_time()

last_two_years = df['2017-10-01': '2020-10-01']
last_two_years.head()
```

```
banana bread    pumpkin bread   isPartial
date            
2017-10-01  24  9   False
2017-10-08  26  11  False
2017-10-15  24  11  False
2017-10-22  24  11  False
2017-10-29  23  12  False
```

Pandas seems to detect the year just fine

```
last_two_years.index[0].year
2017
```

But when I try to plot the data with a monthly tick on the x-axis, I get the following plot:

```
ax = last_two_years.plot(figsize=(20, 5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B, %Y"))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # rotates the date labels
```

[image: my plot with wrong x-axis]

1. Why are my year labels in the 1970's when the data is from 2017 to 2020?
2. Why is `Jul` repeatedly sneaking in there?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There were issues with MPL 3.3.0 and pandas datetime, but they should have been fixed in 3.3.1.   https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17983  If you still have a problem with more recent matplotlib, please open a bug report with a reproducible example.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for the response! I'm using matplotlib 3.3.2 and pandas 1.1.3. Should I open a bug report?

Comment: Maybe?  Can you make your example above complete and self-contained first?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Sure! I updated the example with everything I have in my Jupyter notebook.

Comment: You will get more people helping you if you don't use external libraries.  Can you make a fake data set that does this?

Comment: @JodyKlymak When I retried it without `pytrends` it worked fine. Not really sure what the exact issue was, but it more or less answered my questions above. Could `pytrends` be using an outdated version of the `DataFrame` object?

Comment: I don't know - maybe needs to be reported to pytrends and/or pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the above example without `pytrends` but everything worked fine.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

two_years = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2019-01-01')

# randomly generated dummy data
data1 = np.random.randn(len(two_years))
data2 = np.random.randn(len(two_years))

ts1 = pd.Series(data=data1, index=two_years)
ts2 = pd.Series(data=data2, index=two_years)
data = {'banana bread': ts1, 'pumpkin bread': ts2}
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
```

The data looked the same

```
df.head()

    banana bread    pumpkin bread
2017-01-01  -0.711772   -0.782613
2017-01-02  -0.513398   0.478608
2017-01-03  0.768380    0.286899
2017-01-04  0.073636    1.296839
2017-01-05  -0.408765   -0.828802
```

and Pandas still detected the year correctly

```
df.index[0].year

2017
```

but this time the x-axis labels worked as expected

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20, 5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%B, %Y"))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # rotates the date labels
```

[working x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4OZF.png)

If anyone runs into this in the future and is using the `pytrends` module, that may be causing the issue.